# Remote git worktree is detached

Tags: git, git-worktree

I'm attempting to add a worktree to a remote branch, if the branch isn't stored locally.

I can successfully do this and get all the files using the following command:

```
git worktree add issue origin/issue
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Preparing issue (identifier issue)
HEAD is now at d4bb4b9 Action edit performed on issue: ISSUE-1
```

This makes it seem as if the worktree was successful. If I look at the files, everything is there.

However, the git status command looks like this

```
git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and I can't push/pull anything. Git version is 2.14.1 btw on windows (if it makes a difference)

Does anyone know how to fix this? If the branch is local and you remove the origin/, it works perfectly fine. It's just dealing with the remote that it seems to not agree with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [full syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) is:

```
git worktree add [-f] [--detach] [--checkout] [--lock] [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<commit-ish>]
```

So try:

```
git worktree add --checkout -b issue ../a/path origin/issue
```

The [OP Liam Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4107315/liam-kelly) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554476/remote-git-worktree-is-detached/48556223?noredirect=1#comment84199356_48556223):

> However you don't actually need the `--checkout` for the command, using `-b` is all you need.
> I didn't even think about `-b` being able to create the branch locally from a remote.

Comment: This works perfectly. However you don't actually need the --checkout for the command, using -b is all you need. I didn't even think about -b being able to create the branch locally from a remote. +1!

Comment: @LiamKelly Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

> If the branch is local and you remove the origin/, it works perfectly fine. It's just dealing with the remote that it seems to not agree with.

You can't work on a remote branch (in a worktree or a normal repository). You could just work (push and pull) on local branches.

So you **have to** create the local tracking branch that you will use in the worktree.

Remote branches are updated by git when you push and fetch/pull to mirror the state of the branch in the remote repository at the moment when the command is run.

So you could :

- create a worktree on an existing local branch (other than the current one)
- create a branch  in the same time/command you create the worktree to be able to commit in it.

Comment: You're right in that I had to make the local tracking. For people looking for this solution, you can add remote tracking with the command "git branch -f <local-branch-name> <remote-branch>.